# Registering a new scheduled-task on plugin update

Tags: shopware, shopware6

The documention says:

> Usually scheduled tasks are registered when installing or updating
> your plugin.

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-scheduled-task#executing-the-scheduled-task

Unfortunately it doesn't work on plugin updates.

The manual workaround is to deactivate and activate the plugin.

We're currently implementing an automatic workaround in our plugin update method by dispatching a plugin activation event.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the documentation seems to be misleading there currently. Until this is fixed, the "cleanest" approach would be to register an `UpdateService` in your plugin to re-register the tasks and use it in your `update` method:

```xml
<service id="Foo\MyPlugin\UpdateService" public="true">
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Framework\MessageQueue\ScheduledTask\Registry\TaskRegistry"/>
</service>
```

```php
namespace Foo\MyPlugin;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\MessageQueue\ScheduledTask\Registry\TaskRegistry;

class UpdateService
{
    private TaskRegistry $taskRegistry;

    public function __construct(TaskRegistry $taskRegistry)
    {
        $this->taskRegistry = $taskRegistry;
    }

    public function registerTasks(): void
    {
        $this->taskRegistry->registerTasks();
    }
}
```

```php
class MyPlugin extends Plugin
{
    public function update(UpdateContext $updateContext): void
    {
        if (!$this->container->has(UpdateService::class)) {
            return;
        }

        $this->container->get(UpdateService::class)->registerTasks();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks we'll try that.

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesnt work. In the update process the services.xml is not loaded yet.

Comment: If the plugin isn't active when you try to update, then yes this would be the case. If the plugin is active when you try to update, all its services should be available. If the plugin is inactive when its being updated there would be no need for re-registering the tasks anyways, as they will be registered on the eventual activation. Just check if the container has the service and only call it when it does.

Comment: Sorry, its not working. We double checked it. Even if the plugin is active & you initiate the update, you have no access to the service.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry too. I'm running the exact example above locally without any issues and I never had problems using services like this in a few plugins before. If you actually used the early return of the example above you should've also never received any errors about the service not existing. Did you not make the service public? That would explain why it wouldn't be accessible via the service container.

Comment: Feedback. It works now. You have to clear the cache :-)